# GeoJSON and/or Shapefile: Temporal data w/ multiple dates per feature

Tags: shapefile, geojson, spatio-temporal-data

I have a large dataset that's frequently being updated, and it consists of tens of thousands of geospatial polygons, each of which has one or more (potentially over 100) timestamped average temperature measurements.

My goal is to export this data into GeoJSON or Shapefile format, where each individual Shape/Feature can have a whole series of timestamped measurements attached to it, as opposed to having a separate copy of each polygon for each timestamp.

Is there a standard/accepted way to do this in either of these formats?

Comment: Where is your data be stored? What is the platform or software you are using? Could you give an example of the input data (attribute table with few rows) and output data?

Comment: @ramiroaznar My input data consists of two tables: one is a set of polygons, each with a unique ID; the other is a set of temperature measurements, each with a polygon ID and a timestamp. I don't know what exactly the output should look like; that's the question.

Comment: @ramiroaznar to be clear, I know how to output GeoJSON of the polygons, and can convert to Shapefile using ogr2ogr. What I don't know is how to represent the time series data for each polygon in that polygon's `properties` field.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a feature collection with as many features as timestamps. So for each timestamp you will have a polygon and an average temperature. You will have then overlapping polygons for each location, but if the dataset is displayed over time, only one polygon should be shown. The best data format to store this type of data is geopackage because it is light and will keep your timestamp format.

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is that the polygons are relatively complex, and there may be 100+ timestamped measurements for a given polygon... which means duplicating the polygon coordinates 100x. It's a situation where file size matters (not the primary concern but a concern nonetheless) so I'm hoping not to have to do it that way.

Comment: Then use a PostGIS/Spatial SQLite database and store your geometries and thematic data separately. You can join them using a foreign key.

Comment: The goal is specifically to produce a file that can be easily sent/downloaded/etc, which can then be imported into GIS software... adding a database into the mix isn't an option. If it makes more sense to, say, split it into two files -- say, a GeoJSON or Shapefile plus a CSV file for the time series data, that's probably an acceptable option, though.